# Google Calendar API Push Notification doesn't work with calendars from Google Apps for Work

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm using the Google Calendar API to synchronise calendars with Google Calendar.

In order to update my calendar when an event is change on Google Calendar, I'm using Push Notification. This is working fine with a normal Google account, but I do not get notifications when the calendar belong to a Google for Work account.

Since it's working fine for the normal Google account, I assume there is a security setting somewhere which prevent me to get the notification.

Comment: Do you have more than free-busy access to that google for work calendar from the authenticated account?

Comment: If you mean the user I created to manage the calendar (which is my service account email) in the sharing options, yes, it is set has owner. Otherwise could you be more specific?